# Flutter Future build not showing the container when its loaded

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use futurebuild in my app but after loaded the function its still showing indicator of loading not showing the container

Here is my code

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool showApp = false;
   var _questions = new List<Questions>();
  _getQuestions() {
    API.getUsers().then((response) {
      setState(() {

        Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
        print(list);
        print(list);
        _questions = list.map((model) => Questions.fromJson(model)).toList();
        print(_questions);
        showApp = true;
      });
    });
  }

  int index = 0;
  bool shouldShow = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    int size = _questions?.length;

    void nextQuestion() {
      if (index < size - 1)
        setState(() {
          index++;
        });
      print(index);
    }

    double percentage1Calculate() {
      int wouldClick = 12;
      int ratherClick = 13;
      double percentage1 = wouldClick / (wouldClick + ratherClick) * 100;
      return percentage1;
    }

    double percentage2Calculate() {
      int wouldClick = 2;
      int ratherClick = 3;
      double percentage2 = ratherClick / (wouldClick + ratherClick) * 100;
      return percentage2;
    }

    void percengtageTrigger(){
      setState(() {
        shouldShow = true;
      });
      Timer timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1350), () {
        setState(() {
          shouldShow = false;
        });
      });
    }

    final PrimaryColor = const Color(0xff404040);

    final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(
        'Would you Rather',
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'FredokaOne'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
    );
    double stackHeight = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
        appBar.preferredSize.height -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top);
    double stackWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return FutureBuilder(


        initialData:null, //initial default data if you have some
        future: _getQuestions(),
        builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot){
           if(snapshot.hasData){
             print("Data found, You can continue");
             return Center(
               child: Container(
                 child: Text('data avail'),

               ),
             );
           }
           else if (snapshot.hasError) {
             return Center(
               child: Container(
                 child: Text('error'),

               ),
             );
           }
           else{
             print("loading");
             return CircularProgressIndicator();
           }
        }
    );
  }
}
```

I use _getQuestions in the future but it's just printing the value of the function. Not showing the container of snapshot.hasData

Dont know why the function is printing data but in FutureBuilder its not changing his state :(

Model question

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Questions {
  String would;
  String rather;
  int wouldClick;
  int ratherClick;

  Questions(int wouldClick, int ratherClick, String would, String rather) {
    this.wouldClick = wouldClick;
    this.ratherClick = ratherClick;
    this.would = would;
    this.rather = rather;
  }

  Questions.fromJson(Map json)
      : wouldClick = json['wouldClick'],
        ratherClick = json['ratherClick'],
        would = json['would'],
        rather = json['rather'];

  Map toJson() {
    return {'wouldClick': wouldClick, 'ratherClick': ratherClick, 'would': would, 'rather': rather};
  }
  @override
  String toString() {
    return "{would: $would, rather: $rather, wouldClick: $wouldClick, ratherClick: $ratherClick}";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool showApp = false;
  Future myQuestionsFuture;

  var _questions = new List<Questions>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    myQuestionsFuture = _getQuestions();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<Questions>> _getQuestions() async {
    final response = await API.getUsers();
    Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
    print(list);
    print(list);
    _questions = list.map((model) => Questions.fromJson(model)).toList();
    print(_questions);
    setState(() {
      showApp = true;
    });
    return _questions;
  }

  int index = 0;
  bool shouldShow = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int size = _questions?.length;

    void nextQuestion() {
      if (index < size - 1)
        setState(() {
          index++;
        });
      print(index);
    }

    double percentage1Calculate() {
      int wouldClick = 12;
      int ratherClick = 13;
      double percentage1 = wouldClick / (wouldClick + ratherClick) * 100;
      return percentage1;
    }

    double percentage2Calculate() {
      int wouldClick = 2;
      int ratherClick = 3;
      double percentage2 = ratherClick / (wouldClick + ratherClick) * 100;
      return percentage2;
    }

    void percengtageTrigger() {
      setState(() {
        shouldShow = true;
      });
      Timer timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1350), () {
        setState(() {
          shouldShow = false;
        });
      });
    }

    final PrimaryColor = const Color(0xff404040);

    final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(
        'Would you Rather',
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'FredokaOne'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
    );
    double stackHeight = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
        appBar.preferredSize.height -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top);
    double stackWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return FutureBuilder<List<Questions>>(
        initialData: null, //initial default data if you have some
        future:myQuestionsFuture,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Questions>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print("Data found, You can continue");
              return Center(
                child: Container(
                  child: Text('data avail'),
                ),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                child: Container(
                  child: Text('error'),
                ),
              );
            }
          } else {
            print("loading");
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Its showing this error type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Null>'